# Device UUID not unique when user uninstall and re-install

Tags: ios, swift

I have a system where each user allowed to install apps for two devices only. The issue is happened when user uninstall and reinstall again on the same device. So it will generate new UUID and when the apps check to web service.

The apps will send UUID and login id in order to check if the user with that login id has installed in more than two devices. I am using real iPhone and iPad device, not using simulator. I am not sure for production environment. Currently the apps is distributed using Apple TestFlight using AppStore Distribution profile.

I generate the uuid using this

```
let uuid = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour for `identifierForVendor`.  It is *not* a lifetime-unique device identifier.  You can store your own value in the keychain, but you should also provide a facility for a user to delete obsolete devices; they may replace their phone due to an upgrade or warranty replacement, or simply erase the device, which will clear the keychain

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. How if user use the same iCloud account on two devices. Will both device have same device id (unique id) in the keychain?

Comment: You can choose whether to add a keychain item to the iCloud keychain or keep it local to the device

Comment: @Paulw11 i see. the option to keep local can be set in code or it is depends on users if they sync the keychain?

Comment: It is set programatically when you create the keychain item.  By default it is local to the device only

Comment: @Paulw11 great then. let me try and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use keychain: (to be able to imort JNKeychain you need to enter a new string in your pod file `pod 'JNKeychain'`). This will guaranty you that if you don't change you bundle identifier, you will always have a uniq device id (that will stay the same even after deleting your app). I used that when user was banned forever in our application, he couldn't enter the app even with different account even after deleting the app.

```
import UIKit
import JNKeychain

class KeychainManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = KeychainManager()

    func getDeviceIdentifierFromKeychain() -> String {

        // try to get value from keychain
        var deviceUDID = self.keychain_valueForKey("keychainDeviceUDID") as? String
        if deviceUDID == nil {
            deviceUDID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
            // save new value in keychain
            self.keychain_setObject(deviceUDID! as AnyObject, forKey: "keychainDeviceUDID")
        }
        return deviceUDID!
    }

    // MARK: - Keychain

    func keychain_setObject(_ object: AnyObject, forKey: String) {
        let result = JNKeychain.saveValue(object, forKey: forKey)
        if !result {
            print("keychain saving: smth went wrong")
        }
    }

    func keychain_deleteObjectForKey(_ key: String) -> Bool {
        let result = JNKeychain.deleteValue(forKey: key)
        return result
    }

    func keychain_valueForKey(_ key: String) -> AnyObject? {
        let value = JNKeychain.loadValue(forKey: key)
        return value as AnyObject?
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks for the `KeychainManager` class too

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected bevaiour. If you want to use same UUID you need to save it to the keyChain. I have done something simmiler in of my apps using [KeyChainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper)

So here is a sample chunk for you

```
let deviceId = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString ?? ""
// Saving Id in keyChain
KeychainWrapper.defaultKeychainWrapper().setString(deviceId, forKey: "CurrentDeviceId")
```

And then just get Id from keyChain everytime you want to use it.

```
let previousDeviceId = KeychainWrapper.defaultKeychainWrapper().stringForKey("CurrentDeviceId")
```

Comment: This also works for me but i prefer @Paul solution. Thanks